# How can I populate the datagrid cobmo box column in WPF?

Tags: wpf-controls

I am having problems populating data grid combo box column with combo boxes, the data grid column is not showing any data. But, first things first. Here are my binding classes:

```
 public class StartingEleven
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int shirt_number { get; set; }
            public string position { get; set; }
            public bool captain { get; set; }
            
        }

 public class DGObject
        {
            public string FifaID { get; set; }
            public string Venue { get; set; }
            public string Location { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public int Goals { get; set; }
            public int Penalties { get; set; }
            public string AwayTeamCode { get; set; }
            public int GuestGoals { get; set; }            
            public List<StartingEleven> HomeTeam11 { get; set; }
        }
```

And my root object:

```
 public class RootObject
        {
            public string venue { get; set; }
            public string location { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public string time { get; set; }
            public string fifa_id { get; set; }
            public Weather weather { get; set; }
            public string attendance { get; set; }
            public List<string> officials { get; set; }
            public string stage_name { get; set; }
            public string home_team_country { get; set; }
            public string away_team_country { get; set; }
            public DateTime datetime { get; set; }
            public string winner { get; set; }
            public string winner_code { get; set; }
            public HomeTeam home_team { get; set; }
            public AwayTeam away_team { get; set; }
            public List<HomeTeamEvent> home_team_events { get; set; }
            public List<AwayTeamEvent> away_team_events { get; set; }
            public HomeTeamStatistics home_team_statistics { get; set; }
            public AwayTeamStatistics away_team_statistics { get; set; }
            public DateTime last_event_update_at { get; set; }
            public DateTime last_score_update_at { get; set; }
        }
```

There is a saying: a single picture is worth a thousand words... So, to be more accurate, first, here is my output that I am having problems with:

[image: User control "Matches"]

Here is my method that loads this datagrid:

```
        public static void LoadAllEventsForHomeTeam(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cb, System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dg)
        {
            var url = new Url("http://worldcup.sfg.io/matches/country?fifa_code=");
            string urlEndpoint = GetItemFromComboBoxWpf(cb);
            var request = url + urlEndpoint;
            string cbItem = cb.SelectedItem.ToString();

                    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn c1 = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
                    c1.Header = "Game ID";
                    c1.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("FifaID");
                    c1.Width = 120;
                    dg.Columns.Add(c1);

                    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn c2 = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
                    c2.Header = "City";
                    c2.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Venue");
                    c2.Width = 95;
                    dg.Columns.Add(c2);

                    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn c3 = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
                    c3.Header = "Location";
                    c3.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Location");
                    c3.Width = 150;
                    dg.Columns.Add(c3);

                    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn c4 = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
                    c4.Header = "Date";
                    c4.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Date");
                    c4.Width = 180;
                    dg.Columns.Add(c4);

                    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn c5 = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
                    c5.Header = "Goals";
                    c5.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Goals");
                    c5.Width = 75;
                    dg.Columns.Add(c5);

                    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn c6 = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
                    c6.Header = "Penalties";
                    c6.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Penalties");
                    c6.Width = 100;
                    dg.Columns.Add(c6);

                    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn c7 = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
                    c7.Header = "Guest";
                    c7.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("AwayTeamCode");
                    c7.Width = 90;
                    dg.Columns.Add(c7);

                    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn c8 = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
                    c8.Header = "Guest score";
                    c8.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("GuestGoals");
                    c8.Width = 110;
                    dg.Columns.Add(c8);

                    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridComboBoxColumn c9 = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                    c9.Header = "Team 11";
                    c9.TextBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("HomeTeam11");
                    c9.Width = 110;
                    dg.Columns.Add(c9);
            try
            {

                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(async () =>
                // await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    if (request != null)
                    {
                        List<Teams.RootObject> matches = await request.GetJsonAsync<List<Teams.RootObject>>();
                        foreach (var match in matches)
                        {
                                                    
                            if (cbItem.Contains(match.home_team.code))
                            {


                                dg.Items.Add(new Teams.DGObject
                                {
                                    FifaID = match.fifa_id,
                                    Venue = match.venue,
                                    Location = match.location,
                                    Date = match.datetime.ToLocalTime(),
                                    Goals = match.home_team.goals,
                                    Penalties = match.home_team.penalties,
                                    AwayTeamCode = match.away_team.code,
                                    GuestGoals = match.away_team.goals,
                                    HomeTeam11 = match.home_team_statistics.starting_eleven
                                });

                                }
                            }
                        }                    
                }));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

As you can see, this method loads datagrid with events which are soccer matches for selected team. By selecting an item from combo box, here named cb, a method forms an API call by completing an API call with selected combo box item as endpoint thus loading datagrid with matches that Germany played as a home team. Now, here is the problem: Last column, here named Team11 should contain combo boxes, and combo boxes should contain eleven players (starting eleven) that played that match. Selected team, in this case Germany, obviously, played four matches as home team. So, in column Team11 there should be four comboboxes, one for each game, placed in each row, and each combobox should contain eleven players that played that particular match, but there is no data in column Team11. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: hi perhaps set it programatically?

Comment: Hello! Well, entire datagrid is set programmatically, main problem here is that I have multiple collections, that is, multiple combo boxes... I am having trouble setting particular data from API to grid...